# PySpark not working in my machine, even tough spark-shell works correctly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

sorry but I'm quite new to Spark and PySpark. I installed Spark on my windows machine, and if I run spark-shell I get the Scala environment and everything seems working correctly. The problem is when I try to use PySpark library from a simple Python script.

```
import pandas as pdimport pyspark.sqlfrom pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

```
url = "spark://192.168.3.168:7077"spark = SparkSession.builder.master(url).appName("test-spark").getOrCreate()#spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName("test-spark").getOrCreate()
```

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Brooke", 20), ("Denny", 31), ("Jules", 30), ("TD", 35), ("Brooke", 25)], ["name", "age"])df.printSchema()
```

As soon as I do createDataFrame I get an error like this, both if I use localhost or a Spark installed on a Linux Machine

```
Exception has occurred: Py4JErrorAn error occurred while calling o29.legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement. Trace:py4j.Py4JException: Method legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement([]) does not existat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o29.legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement. Trace:py4j.Py4JException: Method legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement([]) does not existat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

I've tried in another machine and the problem is not raising, I don't know what to do in my machine in order to solve the problem. What can I try?